# How to send the SMS message to multiple users separately (Not at a time) using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, twilio-api

I want to send the SMS to multiple users using node.js code.what is the procedure to be followed? I had little bit experience to send the sms to single user. But **I don't know how to send the sms to multiple users**. I have enclosed the code to send SMS to the single user. **But before 6 Months these code works fine. But now it doesn't work**. Can anyone provide the solution for this two problem?

```html
var accountSid = 'cnsjs'; // Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
var authToken = 'chdcbhh';   // Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console

var twilio = require('twilio');
var client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages.create({
    body: 'Hello hai I am vignesh Ravi . I sent the message from twilio account',
    to:   '+121331161616',  // Text this number
    from: '+18597401144' // From a valid Twilio number
}).then(function(message)
{
    console.log("Messages sent to 1213311161616");
});
```

Comment: What error its showing now?

Comment: It doesn't show anything...

Comment: Then catch err at `.then(function(err,message){//err})`

Comment: in Promises the errors are handled in catch function like `.then(function (data) {}).catch(function (err) {// handle error here})`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send multiple messages at the same time you need to use `Promise.all`. I have updated your code with something that i think will work for you i created it using bluebird.js because i am familiar with it and it has kickass tools.

tri this:

```
var accountSid = 'cnsjs'; // Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
var authToken = 'chdcbhh';   // Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var twilio = require('twilio');
var client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

var promises = [];

// add all the different send promises to this array like following

promises.push(
    client.messages.create({
        body: 'Hello hai I am vignesh Ravi . I sent the message from twilio account',
        to:   '+121331161616',  // Text this number
        from: '+18597401144' // From a valid Twilio number
    })
)

var result = {
    sent: [],
    failed: []
};

var finalPromise = Promise.all(promises.map(function (p) {
    return Promise.resolve(p).reflect(); // resolve will convert it to bluebird promise and reflect will make it always successful
})).each(function (inspection) {
    if (inspection.isFulfilled()) { //this means the send was successful
        result.sent.push(inspection.value());        
    } else { //this means there was an error 
        result.failed.push(inspection.reason());
    }
}).then(function () {
    return result;
})

finalPromise.then(function (res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
})
```

you might have to fix the code a bit before it starts to work as you intend it

**Edit**

i made small changes to code where i am calling the collective promise at the end. give it a try and let me know if it works

Comment: I used my account sid and token. I installed bluebird module I followed your code.but It doesn't show anything....

Comment: i want to send the message to multiple users seperately(Not at a time) .

Comment: Let me take a look at twilio api

Comment: I tried to send a message to single user.but it shows like:{ [Error: The From phone number +18597401144 is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account.]
  status: 400,
  message: 'The From phone number +18597401144 is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account.',
  code: 21606,
  moreInfo: 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21606',
  detail: undefined } but I gave correct number only

Comment: try testing it with some other phone number, just to make sure you can replicate the issue with any number or its specific to certain phone number(s)